# Por que "no Recife" e não "em Recife"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, preposições, artigos-definidos

Acompanhando o noticiário dos últimos dias na TV, percebi que os repórteres e apresentadores diziam

> "... manifestação/protestos **no** Recife."

em lugar de

> "manifestação/protestos **em** Recife."

que me parece mais natural. Qual(is) a(s) razão(ões) para tal escolha dos repórteres e apresentadores?

Comment: Já agora, o título da pergunta. Isto diz-se no Brasil? Em Portugal seria «Por **quê** "no Recife" e não "em Recife?» (na verdade, em Portugal escreve-se «porquê», mas isso é outra história).

Comment: A mim soa-me melhor "no Recife".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O artigo tende a usar-se com topónimos derivados de nomes comuns (*o Funchal*, *o Porto*, *a Guarda*, *o Rio de Janeiro* e por aí adiante). Talvez seja por isso que os jornalistas tendam a dizer *o Recife* — *recife* é um nome comum que significa «Rochedo ou grupo de rochedos à flor da água e um pouco afastados da costa ou praia» ([Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/recife)).

Por vezes, contudo, existe alguma variabilidade. [*Quarteira*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarteira) é frequentemente usado com artigo pelos média, mas os locais não o usam (repara que a Wikipédia também não o usa).

Quanto a Recife, uma pesquisa neste [corpo de texto brasileiro](http://www.linguateca.pt/acesso/corpus.php?corpus=CBRAS), mostra **15686** ocorrências para casos envolvendo «Recife» e uma preposição sem artigo (`[pos="PRP"] "Recife"`) e **13654** ocorrências com artigo (`([pos="PRP\+DET"] | ([pos="PRP"] [pos="DET")) "Recife"`), por isso não parece claro que haja uma forte preferência por alguma das alternativas.

Comment: Eu tenho a impressão, mas não tenho a certeza, que há localidades em Portugal cujo o nome levava  artigo, e que o pessoal começou a omiti-lo. Não sei se não será o caso do Montijo, que eu acho que era *o Montijo, do Montijo*, e agora é oficialmente *de Montijo*. Eu interpretei isso como um tentativa de engrandecer a cidade, já que os nomes das aldeias têm quase sempre artigo. Cidades mais antigas não têm esses complexos, claro.

Answer (score 7):

Em português, os nomes de países e cidades **podem ser precedidos** por artigo definido (masculino ou feminino) ou **podem não ser precedidos** por artigo.  E não existem regras quanto ao artigo a ser usado (o/a) ou se ele é omitido; aprende-se da mesma forma que aprendemos se "laranja", "banana", "abacaxi" e "pêssego" são palavras do gênero masculino ou feminino.

> - **Rio de Janeiro, Recife, Porto, Cairo, Brasil, Japão, Canadá, México, Paquistão, Kenia, Reino Unido, etc**, podem ser precedidos apenas pelo artigo definido masculino "o".
> - **Holanda, Alemanha, Suécia, França, Espanha, Namíbia, Colombia, Nicarágua, Rússia, China, Austrália, Síria,  etc**, podem ser precedidos apenas pelo artigo definido feminino "a"
> - **Portugal, Israel, Marrocos, Barbados, Cuba, Cabo Verde, Honduras, El Salvador, Trinidad, Bangladesh, Singapura, Madagascar, Luxemburgo, São Paulo, Amsterdam, Praga, Veneza, Madrid, Beijing, Shanghai, Mumbai e Buenos Aires**, independente de gênero, não são habitualmente precedidos por artigo definido.
>     Contudo, conforme mencionado por Jacinto, em casos específicos pode-se usar o artigo definido (masculino ou feminino) em concordância com o gênero do substantivo.  ex: **A Veneza (a cidade)  dos meus sonhos, O Portugal (o país) que um dia eu conheci.**

Portanto,

- Vou ao Rio de Janeiro - Estou no Rio de Janeiro
- Vou ao Recife - Estou no Recife
- Vou ao Porto - Estou no Porto
- Vou ao Cairo - Estou no Cairo
- Vou ao México - Estou no México
- Vou à Suécia - Estou na Suécia
- Vou à França - Estou na França
- Vou à Rússia - Estou na Rússia
- Vou à Alemanha - Estou na Alemanha
- Vou à Colombia - Estou na Colombia
- Vou a Amsterdam - Estou em Amsterdam
- Vou a Portugal - Estou em Portugal
- Vou a Buenos Aires - Estou em Buenos Aires
- Vou a Moscou - Estou em Moscou
- Vou a Singapura - Estou em Singapura
- Vou a Luxemburgo - Estou em Luxemburgo

**Especificamente em relação a Recife, o que talvez cause certa confusão é que muitos brasileiros não nativos do Recife consideram que o nome da cidade não deve ser precedido por artigo, e frequentemente dizem "Vou a Recife" e "Estou em Recife".**

Notem que, no Brasil, os nomes de cidades, em sua maioria, não são precedidos de artigo (Porto Alegre, Florianópolis, Vitória, Teresina, Belém, Manaus, João Pessoa, Maceió, Curitiba, Brasilia, São Paulo, Belo Horizonte, etc)
e que os estados tendem a ser precedidos pelo artigo definido masculino (o Amazonas, o Pará, o Paraná, o Piauí, o Rio Grande do Norte/Sul, o Espírito Santo, o Ceará, o Maranhão, o Mato Grosso do Sul, o Tocantins).  Exceções existem, é claro: Minas Gerais, São Paulo, Goiás, a Bahia, etc, etc)

Comment: @DanGetz e Centaurus: não existe género neutro em português. Existem substantivos que normalmente não levam artigo, mas são no entanto masculinos (Portugal é lind***o***) ou femininos (Angola é lind***a***), e em certas construções levam artigo: ***a*** Angola da minha infância; _**um** imens**o** Portugal_ ([Chico Buarque, *Fado Tropical*,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfjaFMah7sE) com letra um bocado obscura).