# Poderíamos usar "Portugal" no plural?

Tags: número-gramatical, concordância-nominal

Sei que existem formas mais simples ou mais idiomáticas de se expressar, mas eu procuro saber se poderia usar "Portugal" no plural na seguinte frase:

O território brasileiro é tão grande que nele cabem mais de 90 _________.

Com Portugal, realmente a frase soa-me estranha independente do número gramatical.  Já "Inglaterras" e "Espanhas" não soam tão estranho.  Sem falar em Estados Unidos, que já está no plural.

Repito, não estou procurando frases mais idiomáticas, elas existem e todos nós as conhecemos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Portugais* é até uma palavra relativamente comum; e *Brasis* também. E aos meus ouvidos a frase soa-me perfeitamente idiomática. Eu já disse várias vezes esse tipo de frase, que o Brasil faz cem ou noventa e cinco Portugais, conforme me saem as contas. Mas alguém num [seminário do Conselho de Arquitetura e Urbanismo do Brasil](http://www.caubr.gov.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Seminario-Internacional-Relatorio-Site-Portugues.pdf) apurou o número exato (ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> O Brasil equivale a 92 vezes Portugal. Imagina **92 Portugais** juntinhos—esse é o Brasil.

Outras comparações esse tipo :

> “[...] onde cabem, por exemplo, 90 ilhas de São Tomé e Príncipe em território europeu de Portugal, **14 Portugais** em Angola, e quase **sete Angolas** no Brasil”. [(Jornal da USP, 2004.)](http://www.usp.br/jorusp/arquivo/2004/jusp695/pag02.htm)
>
> Em 2016, 7.989 km2 de floresta viraram cinza na Amazônia, causando emissão de carbono equivalente a **dois Portugais**;
>   [(Observatório do Clima, 2016.)](http://www.observatoriodoclima.eco.br/desmatamento-sobe-29-o-maior-em-8-anos/)

Mais frequentes são entanto as referências figuradas a diferentes Portugais, um rural, outro urbano, um jovem, outro idoso; e coisas assim. E encontramos isto em publicações prestigiadas e nos melhores escritores. Exemplos:

> **Dois Portugais** antagônicos coexistiram por algum tempo, baralhando-se e confundindo-se na fervura das guerras e revoluções, antes de vencer o Portugal burguês e comercial.
>   [(Gilberto Freyre, *Casa Grande e Senzala*, 1946.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=wncpAQAAIAAJ&q=Dois%20Portugais%20antag%C3%B4nicos%20coexistiram&dq=Dois%20Portugais%20antag%C3%B4nicos%20coexistiram&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8leutpvnQAhXESBQKHYlUAg0Q6AEIMTAC)
>
> Eu, português conheço pelo menos **dois Portugais**: um dos portugueses, e outro das portuguesadas.
>   [(Almada Negreiros, *Obras Completas*, 1993.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=U4vuAAAAMAAJ&q=%22dois%20portugais%22&dq=%22dois%20portugais%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOm_u9pfnQAhUL6xQKHfZ8A5AQ6AEI5QEwHQ)
>
> Portanto temos aqui três gerações que representam **três ‘Portugais’** distintos.
>   [(Henrique Raposo, “Três ‘Portugais’ ”, *Expresso*, 2009.)](http://expresso.sapo.pt/opiniao/HenriqueRaposo/tres-portugais=f530857)
>
> Certamente, não há apenas o Portugal grande de Camões e de Pessoa: há **muitos Portugais** (o de Camilo, o de Eça, o de Oliveira Martins), tantos quantas vivências há na nação criadora.
>   [(Jorge Chichorro Rodrigues, *Ser Português*, 1999.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=dNWgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22muitos%20portugais%22&dq=%22muitos%20portugais%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjY3ejgqPnQAhULthQKHTDAD0cQ6AEIKjAB)
>
> Os sociólogos dizem que existem **dois Brasis e dois Portugais**
>   [(*O Novo Conto Brasileiro*, 1985.)](https://www.google.pt/search?q=Os%20soci%C3%B3logos%20dizem%20que%20existem%20dois%20Brasis%20e%20dois%20Portugais&num=50&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT7fnvp_nQAhXLORQKHSrqBdwQ_AUIDCgF&biw=1242&bih=580)

Comment: "Brasis" é uma expressão bastante comum, dada a quantidade de paradoxos que o país historicamente construiu. Uma busca rápida por bases de estudos acadêmicos retorna vários resultados: http://search.scielo.org/?q=brasis&where=ORG

Comment: @RamonMelo Eu encontrei vários *Brasis* só ao buscar *Portugais*. *Portugais* é muito comum também. É, é difícil de pesquisar na net: tens que procurar *dois/três/muitos Portugais*; case contrário,por muito que me esforçasse, não me conseguia livrar do *portugais* francês.

Comment: É, encontrei o mesmo problema na busca acadêmica, agravado pela minha ignorância de que _Portugal_ poderia adquirir gênero masculino (valeria o +1 por esta informação somente).

Comment: @RamonMelo Como foi isso? Buscaste *muitas Portugais*?

Comment: Sim. A maioria dos países tradicionais adquire gênero feminino nas variações da língua portuguesa a que tenho acesso: a Espanha, a Itália, a França, a China, etc. Assumi, na falta de melhor juízo, que Portugal seguiria esta _norma_. Mas, como se diz na linguagem da internet, TIL (_hoje eu aprendi_).

Comment: Já agora, @RamonMelo, "Portugal" é sempre masculino. Não "pode adquirir" género, simplesmente por vezes não leva artigo. Como Fran;a, que é sempre feminino mas nem sempre leva o artigo. Acho que havia uma pergunta sobre isto, mas não a consigo encontrar...

Comment: @ANeves Eu respondi a uma. Basicamente só os países acabados na letra ***a*** é que são femininos, e mesmo assim não todos (Canadá, Gana). Talvez haja algumas micronações que sejam exceções.

Comment: @ANeves Estou curioso para ler as respostas a esta pergunta. Desconfio que estamos entrando em diferenças regionais nesta discussão. _Portugal_ não adquire gênero nenhum por aqui. Diz-se "vou a Portugal", "volto de Portugal". _França_, por outro lado, sempre força a flexão ao feminino: "vou à França", "volto da França. Um exemplo de país que possui gênero, mas faculta o uso do artigo seria _Marrocos_, já que - novamente, por aqui - aceita-se igualmente "voltei de Marrocos" e "voltei do Marrocos". Mas, logicamente, gostaria de ler a argumentação em contrário para formar uma opinião.

Comment: @Ramon Isto é um mal-entendido acerca de *adquir género*. *Portugal* é nome masculino e *Angola* é nome feminino; são é ambos normalmente usados sem artigo. Mas podemos ver o género em *Portugal é lind**o**; Angola é lind**a***; mesmo com estes nomes usamos artigo em coisas como *saudade **do meu** Portugal; **a** Angola da minha infância era muito diferente d**a** atual*.

Comment: Eu concordo. Não estava sendo sarcástico quando disse que "hoje eu aprendi", e peço desculpas se passei esta impressão. Mas, de fato, esta foi a primeira vez que me deparei com _Portugal_ forçando uma flexão dos adjuntos adnominais.

Comment: @Ramon vem ao [falatório](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25826/falatorio), para não atulhar a pergunta com conversa.

Comment: @Ramon Tens [aqui](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3784/when-to-use-em-no-or-na-before-a-country-or-city-name/3785#3785) uma resposta minha acerca do género dos nomes dos países.